# The Existence of a Natural Isomorphism Confirming the Existence of a Limit, as a Commutativity Diagram

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, diagram-chasing

I am reading [Category Theory for Programmers](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/10/28/category-theory-for-programmers-the-preface/) and I am having some trouble in Part 2, Chapter 2: Limits and Colimits.

The author writes:

> Now that we have two functors, we can talk about natural transformations between them. So without further ado, here’s the conclusion: A functor $D$ from $I$ to $C$ has a limit $\lim D$ if and only if there is a natural isomorphism between the two functors I have just defined:
>   $$C(c, \lim D) ≃ Nat(Δc, D)$$

How can you express the existence of this natural isomophism as a commutative diagram?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "as a diagram"?

Comment: @Hurkyl A commutative diagram with objects $I$, $C$ and possibly a topos like $\mathbf{Set}$ for the Hom-objects, and functors as arrows $D$, $\Delta_c$, $C(-,\lim D)$, $Nat(\Delta_-, D)$ such that there's some dotted arrow representing this natural isomorphism which makes the diagram commute if it exists, thus proving the existence of the limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you write above is actually a description of the relevant diagram!

For an object $c\in \mathcal C$, and $D\in\mathcal{C^D}$, what is a natural transformation $\gamma\in\mathrm{Nat}(\Delta c,D)$ like? Like usual, it's going to need to satisfy the commutativity condition $\gamma_{d'}\circ\Delta c(f)=D(f)\circ\gamma_d$ for all $f:d\to d'$ in $\mathcal D$; however, no matter what $f$ is, by definition $\Delta c(f)$ is just $id_c$, so we can simplify that condition to $\gamma_{d'}=D(f)\circ \gamma_d$. But that makes $\gamma$ precisely a cone over $D$. In particular, the limiting cone is just the cone $\alpha:\Delta\circ\lim D\to D$ corresponding to $id_{\lim D}$ by the above isomorphism.

Moreover, given such a $\gamma$, the isomorphism above means it corresponds to a unique morphism $\mathcal C(c,\lim D)$ that is the arrow $f_\gamma$ typically drawn as "the dotted line" on paper. To see why this has the desired property, remember that the isomorphism $\phi:\mathcal C(-,lim D)\to\mathrm{Nat}(\Delta -,D)$ is natural, so that $$\mathrm{Nat}(\Delta(f_\gamma),D)\circ\phi_{\lim D}=\phi_c\circ\mathcal C(f_\gamma,\lim D).$$ If you chase what happens to $id_{\lim D}$ in this square, you'll see that this says exactly that composing the limiting cone with $f_\gamma$ gives you the cone $\gamma$.

Comment: Do you think you could maybe draw it up in [this](http://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/) very nice editor and paste the generated tikzcd code? (More info [here](https://github.com/yishn/tikzcd-editor).)

Comment: I'm not sure how I'm going to draw an arbitrary limit diagram, which might be infinite...

Comment: All right, I'll try to follow your instructions. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: If it makes it easier, just try to use a simple category for $\mathcal D$, like $\mathbb N$ with its usual ordering, or the diagram $\bullet\rightarrow\bullet\leftarrow\bullet$ (which is the shape whose limits are pullbacks).

Comment: I think my core confusion lies in formulating what the two functors actually do: how their mappings work, and consequently what their mutual naturality condition looks like. I've drawn a VERY big diagram trying to explain it to myself.

Comment: So $\Delta$ is easy to describe: it takes $c$ to the functor $\Delta c:\mathcal D\to\mathcal C$, which takes every $d\in\mathrm{Obj}(\mathcal D)$ to $c$ and every morphism in $\mathcal D$ to $id_c$; it takes a morphism $f:c\to c'$ to the natural transformation whose every component is $f$. On the other hand, the text you quote above is *not* assuming that $\lim$ is a functor. Instead, you really just want to think of it as the unique (up to isomorphism) object that represents the functor $\mathrm{Nat}(\Delta-,D)$.

Comment: I was trying to think of it as "select a limit-object candidate, if it is the limit, a natural iso exists between this Hom functor and this Nat functor, otherwise it isn't." Is that completely wrong?

Comment: It's much better in this context not to think of $\lim$ as an operation at all, but to think of "$\lim D$" as a single, indivisible term--you could just use a special variable $c_D$ or something instead. If $\mathcal C$ has a limit for all diagrams of shape $\mathcal D$, then it will happen that the "$\lim$" notation can be used for an actual functor; but if not it's just a notational device. I think you'll want to focus on understanding the case where $D$ is held constant, ignoring the question of whether $\lim$ is functorial, until you understand how that works.